# How to run a query across three tables in MySQL using Joins?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have studied a lot of the questions on Stackoverflow that cover this type of question, but I could not get the solution I seek.

Here are my tables:

```
STUDENT
studentID   lastName   firstName
08422567    Brown      Susan
10356844    Black      Roger
10659475    White      Steven
09463729    Grey       Naomi


MODULE
moduleID   moduleName
CE1181     Biometrics
CE1183     Intelligent Systems
CE1133     Databases
CE1186     HCI

GRADES
studentID*  moduleID*  grade
10356844    CE1181     A
10356844    CE1183     B
10356844    CE1133     C
10356844    CE1186     A
08422567    CE1181     B
08422567    CE1183     B
08422567    CE1133     B
08422567    CE1186     B
10659475    CE1181     C
10659475    CE1183     C
10659475    CE1133     A
10659475    CE1186     C
09463729    CE1181     A
09463729    CE1183     B
09463729    CE1133     B
09463729    CE1186     B
```

The query I need to run is:

```
Select all from students whose id begins with 10 and their grade for intelligent systems was a B
```

Now, I know that I need to join tables together, I have built my tables so that the grades table contains foreign keys connecting to the student and module tables.

As a beginner, this type of query is quite hard to get my hard around, I hope I am close to the answer, this is what I have:

```
SELECT * FROM student WHERE studentID LIKE '10%' INNER JOIN grades
ON student.studentID=grades.studentID  INNER JOIN module
ON grades.moduleID =module.moduleID
```

Of course it does not work, but am I along the right tracks? The correct solution to this question would be a great thing to keep in a code toolbox for use later on!

Comment: Have you tried placing `WHERE` clause **after** your `JOIN`s?

Comment: I am positive I tried that at one point in the many hours of trying this, I thought I tried every combination before posting my question here.

Comment: A good place to look for info like this is the MySQL documentation.  It can be a little hard to read at first, but become familiar with it to help with your learning.  For example, check this link to the syntax for the `SELECT` statement:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: Thanks Bob, I do try and read the documentation, but it overwhelms me and due to having little time to get things done I always try and find shortcuts which the majority of the time do not get me to my goal. But I agree its the place to get the info!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost there, but the `WHERE` needs to go after the `JOIN` clauses. I've used aliases to simply syntax.

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM   grades g 
       JOIN module m 
         ON m.moduleid = g.moduleid 
       JOIN student s 
         ON s.studentid = g.studentid 
WHERE  g.studentid LIKE '10%' 
       AND g.grade = 'B' 
       AND m.modulename = 'Intelligent Systems'
```

**Result**

```
| STUDENTID | LASTNAME | FIRSTNAME |
------------------------------------
|  10356844 |    Black |     Roger |
```

[See the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51c37/3)

Comment: Genius! Thank you! :) It works perfectly! i need to analyse how it compares to my attempt, I want to understand how it works. Thank you very much for this it is appreciated!!!!

Comment: I accept this as my answer, purely because it is a great solution, and it was the first one I could see on the page. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE` clause should follow after `FROM` clause.

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*, c.*   -- deselect the columns you don't want to show
FROM    student a
        INNER JOIN grades b
            ON a.studentID = b.studentID  
        INNER JOIN module c
            ON b.moduleID = c.moduleID
WHERE   a.studentID LIKE '10%' AND
        b.grade = 'B' AND
        c.modulename = 'Intelligent Systems'
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed377/1)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

RESULT

```
╔═══════════╦══════════╦═══════════╦══════════╦═══════╦═════════════════════╗
║ STUDENTID ║ LASTNAME ║ FIRSTNAME ║ MODULEID ║ GRADE ║     MODULENAME      ║
╠═══════════╬══════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬═══════╬═════════════════════╣
║  10356844 ║ Black    ║ Roger     ║ CE1183   ║ B     ║ Intelligent Systems ║
╚═══════════╩══════════╩═══════════╩══════════╩═══════╩═════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it looks the same as the other answer which works, I have tried yours and it works too! I appreciate your help, and those links are great, especially the visual representation of joins, I am away to read them now! :)

Comment: Sorry I never saw your answer before the other one I can only select one answer which sucks :(